# ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 15 and input n_features is 90

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am trying to select features from a model and work with those only such that I can see if my accuracy increases

I have tried doing this manually but it's not favourable as the model has already transformed the dataset to a nndarray.

This is what I am trying to run

```
latest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators= 300, min_samples_leaf= 9, min_samples_split=2, max_depth=25, max_features='auto', criterion= 'entropy',bootstrap=True,oob_score =True)
latest.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred_latest = latest.predict(X_test)
print_score(pred_latest,latest)

#get the features in the data that fit this threshold
xfm = SelectFromModel(latest,threshold = 0.011)

xfm.fit_transform(X_train, y_train)

#let's put the most important fetures into a new data set
X_imp_train = xfm.transform(X_train)
X_imp_test = xfm.transform(X_test)

X_imp_train.shape, X_imp_test.shape
((120846, 15), (15133, 15))


#now let's run it with the best features only
latest_c = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators= 1000,n_jobs=-1,bootstrap=True )

#fit the model
latest_c.fit(X_imp_train, y_train)
```

This is the error I get when I run that code, i really don't understand why I am getting this error, I am getting the same dimensions on the datasets when I run the shape function, where am I missing it?

```
~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/tree/tree.py in _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
    400                              "match the input. Model n_features is %s and "
    401                              "input n_features is %s "
--> 402                              % (self.n_features_, n_features))
    403 
    404         return X

ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 15 and input n_features is 90
```

I would like to fit the new data with only specific features based on the threshold I chose such  that I can move forward with testing.

Comment: in which line of given code does this error happen?

Comment: ```
#fit the model
latest_c.fit(X_imp_train, y_train)
```